# spring boot field always null even after post-ing

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a `LoginCredential` class :

```
public class LoginCredential {
    @Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;
    String eMail;
    String passwordHash;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    User user;
    LoginCredential(){}
    public LoginCredential(String eMail, String passwordHash, User user) 
    {
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Then I have `User` class :

```
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = LoginCredential.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "userID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private LoginCredential loginCredential;
    public User(){}
    public User(String eMail)
    {
          this.eMail=eMail;
    }
    public User(String eMail, LoginCredential loginCredential) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.loginCredential = loginCredential;
    }
}
```

In my system, first of all an instance of `LoginCredential` gets created.

**But for me the problem is after I create that instance, the `user` field remains `null`**.

How to resolve this?

As they are *One to one* mapped, is there other way(s) of doing it?

I have tried this : `{"email":"test@gmail.com","passwordHash":"a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3","user":{"userID":801,"email":"test@gmail.com"}}`

The method I'm using in front end, in my `react.js` application :

```js
createUserAndCredential = () => {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/login/');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    email: this.state.email,
    passwordHash: this.state.passwordHash
  }));
  let that = this;
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
      /*
      console.log(this.responseText);
      console.log(that.state.newLoginCredential);
      */

      that.state.newLoginCredential = this.responseText.toString();


      var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr1.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/user/');
      xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      console.log(that.state.newLoginCredential);

      let user = JSON.stringify({
        email: that.state.email,
        loginCredential: JSON.parse(that.state.newLoginCredential)
      });

      //console.log(loginCredential);

      xhr1.send(user);

    } else if (this.readyState !== 4 && this.status !== 200) {
      console.log(this.status);
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Which gives me this warning :

> *Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"email":"t7@gmail.com","passwordHash":"a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3"}'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"email":"t7@gmail.com","passwordHash":"a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3"}')
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 43] (through reference chain: com.mua.cse616.Model.User["loginCredential"])]*

Answer (score 3):

Since mapping is on the side of `User` (`mappedBy` resides there), you would have to save it to see the changes populated to `LoginCredential`. But you can define the changes in parent to cascage to child:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Or if you don't want to cascade everything (for example removal):

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
```

Comment: still the `user` field is `null`. here : `{"userID":993,"passwordHash":"a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3","user":null, "email":"t7@gmail.com"}]`

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code I'm using to create this instances, can you please see it.